# What is the correct way to extract bytes of a response from an external Rest API producing content in PDF Content Type in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, pdf

The external API returns the pdf as a response with response headers with Content-Type as 'application/pdf' and I would like to extract the bytes response from the REST response.

Then will use these bytes to load a PDF document.

Now what exactly I did is as below:

```
private static byte[] invokeGetPDFDocument(String pdfUrl) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(pdfUrl).get().build();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        byte[] bytes = response.body().bytes();
        File file = new File("test.pdf");
        writeByte(bytes, file);
        return  bytes;
    }
```

Is the above logic correct? Does the pdf response always comes as a part of the rest response body?

The below(i.e writing into a file) is done just for the sake of testing whether the bytes generated is in correct format or not.
Also, do consider the fact that when the response from the API call from the code is written in the **test.pdf** file, its different from the pdf response saved as part of the postman call?

What actually is happening is the below after receiving in bytes:

```
public static BufferedImage getLabelImage(String carrier, byte[] imgBytes, int rotation) {
        log.info("Calling {} API for generating label ...", carrier);
        try {
            if(imgBytes != null && imgBytes.length>0) {
               PDDocument pddoc = PDDocument.load(imgBytes);
               PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pddoc);
               BufferedImage bufferedImage = 
                     pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);
               return bufferedImage;
            }
        } catch (CarrierServiceException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.info("Error getting label image ...");
        }
        return getDefaultLabelImage();
    }
```

Main method::

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String pdfUrl = "testURL";
        byte[] pdfBytes = invokeGetPDFDocument1(pdfUrl);
        BufferedImage image = getLabelImage("testCarrier", pdfBytes, 0);
    }
```

This is where its failing when converting into BufferedImage from Bytes?? This is exactly what i need help for?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Client API and get the InputStream from the response

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        String pdfUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/test";
        Response response = client.target(pdfUrl).request().get();
        String location = "test.pdf";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(location);
        InputStream is = (InputStream)response.getEntity();
        int len = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea, in general, is correct. but there are few pointers:
 1. If your method already writes retrieved response into a file, then why do you want to return the same content as byte array? There is no need for it. You can return either a full file path to your newly written file or the file itself.
 2. I assume that `writeByte(bytes, file);` is your own method that writes the bytes to a file. (Maybe change the method name to `writeBytesToFile(bytes, file);`).
 3. I see that you use OK Http client library which is a good choice. I may suggest an alternative that may be simpler. It's called MgntUtils library. It has `HttpClient` class. Your code would look like this:

```
private static void testHttpClient() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.setConnectionUrl("http://www.your-pdf-url.com/");
    ByteBuffer content = null;
    try {
        content = client.sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(HttpMethod.GET);
        // Here write the code that will write returned ByteBuffer into a file
    } catch (IOException e) {
        content = TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, false);
    }
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Here is the JavaDoc for [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The library itself is available as Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and on GitHub [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including sources and JavaDoc). Also, an article about the library (not including HttpClient description though) can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/michaelgantman/2016/01/26/open-source-java-library-with-stacktrace-filtering-silent-string-parsing-and-version-comparison)

Comment: Ok, but then why do you need to write it in the file AND return bytes as well. Seems like a duplication. Just return the bytes. But then may be you have you're reason for writing the file too...

Comment: i just updated my question. Hope that will explain.